# ShadCN accordion not closing properly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using accordion component provided by ShadCN (latest version) dynamically using map function to render Accordion Item JSX dynamically. But the issue that I have been facing is that the accordion when collapsed again re-collapses another time, the reason of which i am unable to find. any help is appreciated.

Interestingly enough, i found that it was only happening for the dynamically rendered accordion item and not for the static one. Here is the JSX code that i am using.
accordionArr is an array of JS objects in the format of  {heading: string, content: JSX_to_be_rendered_as_content}

```
import {
    Accordion,
    AccordionContent,
    AccordionItem,
    AccordionTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/accordion";

const CustomAccordion = ({accordionArr}) => {
    const constructedAccordion = accordionArr.map((accItem, idx) => {
        return (
            <AccordionItem key={`${accItem.heading}${idx}`} value={`item-${idx+3}`}>
                <AccordionTrigger className="text-lg font-secondary capitalize font-medium">{accItem.heading}</AccordionTrigger>
                <AccordionContent className="text-sm px-7 font-normal grid grid-cols-2 gap-x-7 gap-y-3">
                    {accItem.content}
                </AccordionContent>
            </AccordionItem>
        );
    })

    return ( 
        <Accordion type="single" collapsible>
            <AccordionItem className="AccordionItem" value="item-1">
                <AccordionTrigger>Is it accessible?</AccordionTrigger>
                    <AccordionContent><p>
                        Yes. It adheres to the WAI-ARIA design pattern.
                        <input type="text"></input>
                        </p>
                        </AccordionContent>
                </AccordionItem>

            {...constructedAccordion}
                <AccordionItem className="AccordionItem" value="item-2">
                    <AccordionTrigger>Is it unstyled?</AccordionTrigger>
                    <AccordionContent>
                        Yes. It's unstyled by default, giving you freedom over the look and feel.
                    </AccordionContent>
                </AccordionItem>
        </Accordion>
    );
}
 
export default CustomAccordion;
```